# Count the number of key value pairs in a given JSON structure using jq

Tags: json, jq

Given a JSON structure that looks similar to this:

```
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "baz": 5,
  "qux": false
}
```

How do I find out how many key value pairs are in it? In JavaScript I could call `Object.keys(myJson).length` to get the result, but it would be much more convenient for me to do it with `jq` directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `length` directly on the object.

From the [manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#length):

> The length of an object is the number of key-value pairs

```bash
{"foo":"bar", "baz":5, "qux":false} | length
```

```json
3
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/6A46L4RgrIY)

Answer (score 1):

If the object is the input to JQ, then simply `length`:

```
echo '{"a":4,"b":2}' | jq 'length'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jq 'keys | length'`, which will do exactly the same as `Object.keys(myJson).length`.

Comment: Or simply `jq length` :)